# Is it necessary to create reducer for every action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux, I'm currently struggling with the concept when to create an action and when the action should call the reducer.

Let's say i want to do a post req to send my data to backend, i created an action and called axios in it, and then despatched the action. Do I need a Reducer Here..?

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create an action when we need to modify our state for example, get user information, modify, delete value, and for our state to be updated we need to use our reducer.

Comment: let's say i want to do a post req to send my data to backend, i created an action and called axios in it, and then despatched the action. Do I need a Reducer Here..?

Comment: If your Ws call has an answer and you want to use those answers, you have to call the action and reducer, but if you just want to call a WS and you don't take the result into account, what's the point of using redux, makes Axios call directly into your container.